# Why I can't use ContainedButton in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to change the theme for my RaisedButton, but can't find `ButtonTheme`. Then I read here "https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54776" that they're changing names: RaisedButton => ContainedButton, FlatButton => TextButton, etc.

After upgrading my flutter to the latest version (Channel master, 1.25.0-5.0.pre.108, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.630], locale zh-CN), I still can't get access to `ContainedButtonTheme` or `ContainedButton`. `TextButton` and `TextButtonTheme` worked fine, though.

What did I miss? Thank you!

Comment: I cannot find any `ContainedButton` class in my SDK, maybe you mean `ElevatedButton`?

Comment: @pskink Thank you, I'll try that. I read about `ContainedButton` from the url above. Since `TextButton` has already been ready to use, I assumed the same with `ContainedButton`.

Comment: and what does the official documentation for `RaisedButton` say?

Comment: @pskink Can't find official docs on it. That's why I asked here. ElevatedButton did work, thank you!

Comment: type `RaisedButton` in your IDE and then ctrl-click on it, what do you see in the comments above the class definition?

Comment: btw here you have the official docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html